# Windows 10, how can I find out what ran a powershell script at a certain time

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, logging, event-log

I have a blocked powershell.exe writing to a protected folder. is there any log that can tell me what triggered the powershell.exe? i have the timestamp of when it was blocked.

Comment: How have you blocked it? The record you're looking for will need to be in the Event Logs. Have you looked there?

Comment: See answer here. To also get ParentProcessID change `wscript.echo objReceivedEvent.ProcessName & "    " & itm.CommandLine` to `wscript.echo objReceivedEvent.ProcessName & "    " & itm.CommandLine & "    " & itm.ParentProcessID`

Comment: Just curious. Since the OP is asking about PowerShell, why suggest VBScript code stuff when you can do this just as easily in Powershell proper natively, via the built-in cmdlets for processes.

Comment: @postanote I started programming in BASIC in 1974. WTF would I change. No one taught me because every person already knows how to program is BASIC - it is the same as algebra. Contrast to C and C based languages which is all about how a CPU works. Anyway the question isn't a powershell question.

Comment: I've been programming since 1977, so, been there done that, but we all must continue to ramp up on as many of the new goodies. ***ABL (Always be learning)***

Answer (score 1):

Users write to logs not an executable.

If you want to track PowerShell code (command/script) actions, you need to enable full Powershell Logging/Auditing via GPO/LPO as well as transcript logging and then as noted, dig at event logs or set alerts to notify you.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_eventlogs?view=powershell-5.1

https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-logging-2
[image]

Lastly, powershell.exe is not Powershell. powershell.exe is just a host to run PowerShell code/commands.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54xwcNMb1wo
https://leanpub.com/thebigbookofpowershellgotchas

One can write my own PowerShell host and run any PowerShell command/script(s) one chooses.

Heck, one could just rename powershell.exe to something else to run it.